# Kinect - Tracking people in a crowd - Sports Motion Tracking

Tags: kinect, tracking, processing

I'm interested in programming the Kinect to track people over a largish area.

In particular, I'm looking to track players on a small sports field using gestures to record events in a sports game.

So far I have not found any examples of this being done before, other than Processing examples of tracking players on recorded video.

Could anybody please provide any examples of Microsoft's Kinect technology being applied to sport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what the Kinect is designed to do, and is not something that it will do for you.

The Kinect is capable to tracking no more then 6 people at a time, and only 2 people actively.  It works best for people 6-8 feet away and will not track anyone much further then that.

For what you are proposing the Kinect would not benefit you.  It would probably hinder you, since it is designed for 1-2 persons at a limited distance.  You would be better off with a higher quality camera.

Comment: As long as you use the sdk, you can process the data yourself. It's definitely possible.

Comment: Yes, you could process the data yourself.  I didn't say that this is not possible with the Kinect.  The Kinect would, however, be of no particular benefit in this scenario for the various reasons I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

I never used or tried Kinect (but i really want to get one:). So i don't know if it suits what you need. But there is [this amazing tutorial](http://www.creativeapplications.net/processing/kinect-physics-tutorial-for-processing/) from Amnon Owed on Kinect and processing. The example is with one person but might be of your interest. The video is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You will need to depart from the skeleton tracking available to you in the Kinect SDK and process the depth data yourself. You'll need multiple Kinects to handle a larger area. Topdown-mounted from the ceiling will let you more easily distinguish individuals that would be grouped together in a multi-person blob using side view.

Comment: This is true for a *small* enclosed area that can be covered with the FOV of several Kinects.  However, a "largish area", per the question, is something very different.  A sports field, generally outside but even if not, would require mounting the Kinects several meters from the players - far enough to eliminate any useful depth information.  The RGB camera would be the only reliable data, and better data can be obtained from other devices.

Comment: XBox 360 kinects will distinguish objects from background up to 25 feet away in my own tests, which can be accomplished with some camera rigging in a gym. Admittedly, there is a tradeoff in decreased information at this distance. It all depends what exactly you are doing whether this approach makes sense.